# How to add more than two TypeFilter to FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest?

Tags: android, google-places-api

I'm migrating to new google places sdk client and I want to set more than 2 filter to FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest but I can not find the solution

```
var autoCompleteRequest = FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest.builder().setLocationBias(
            bounds).setCountry("TR").setQuery(query).setSessionToken(
            AutocompleteSessionToken.newInstance()).setTypeFilter(ADDRESS).build()
```

As you can see I can only set one filter also I want to set ADDRESS and ESTABLISHMENT together, I tried to set list of filter but doesn't work

sdk version

```
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0'
```

Comment: Hi, did you find the solution yet?

Comment: @DarkLeonhart I didnt find any solution, I just return all results temporarily .

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove setTypeFilter and by default it works with both.

```
 val request = FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest.builder()
        .setCountry(country)
        .setSessionToken(token)
        .setQuery(constraint.toString())
        .build()
```

Comment: [An empty type filter. All results will be returned.](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/AutocompleteFilter#TYPE_FILTER_NONE) I don't want to return all results.

Comment: I am also trying to do this: autocompletesupportfragment.setTypeFilter(TYPE_FILTER_ADDRESS|TYPE_FILTER_ESTABLISHMENT) and I am faced with this error: setTypeFilter(com.google.android.libraries.places.api.model.TypeFilter) in AutocompleteSupportFragment cannot be applied to (int) - What can I do?

Answer (score -1):

You can use a binary mask like:

```
.setTypeFilter(TYPE_FILTER_CITIES|TYPE_FILTER_ADDRESS)
```

Comment: this method for AutocompleteFilter my object is FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest is it same thing ?